# How to add a line to .bash_profile

Tags: bash, osx-lion, path

I just installed Homebrew on bash on my Mac and now I need to do this:

> Once you’ve installed Homebrew, insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH
> environment variable. You can do this by adding the following line at the bottom of your
> `~/.bashrc` file.
>
> `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

"ls -a" shows `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc.save`.

Do I add this line to `.bash_profile`? How?

Sorry. I'm new to everything.

Answer (score 77):

You can run this command in Terminal, which will append the line to your `.bash_profile`:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: haha - just be sure to use two carats `>>` instead of one `>`. Had a friend just completely wipe mine by accident trying to append.

Comment: How can I update existing export in a bash_profile?

Comment: @ryantuck friends are the worst..

Answer (score 14):

`.bash_profile` is a script that is executed each time you start a new shell. On Linux, it's called under different circumstances than `.bashrc`, but on OS X, they work exactly the same way. Any command you add to the file will be run whenever you open a new terminal window (thus starting a new interactive shell).

`$PATH` is a variable that tells the shell where to look for executable files - so when you type a command, the system will search each directory specified in that variable until it finds an executable program with that command's name.

The command `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` prepends the directory `/usr/local/bin` to the current PATH, so it becomes the first directory searched by the shell.

`.bash_profile` just a normal plain text file - you can edit it with any text editor, including `vi` or `nano`, or even a graphical editor like TextEdit. It's up to you - just remember to save it as a plain-text file.

Answer (score 5):

open .bash_profile with your favorite tekst editor

for example you can use 'vi'

open your terminal and make sure you are in your home directory

type vi .bash_profile and press enter

in vi, type i to be able to type

enter your line

press escape

hold shift and press z twice (z z) to save and quit

that's it!

Comment: Nice you explained how to exit Vi :D

Answer (score 3):

> How to add a line to .bash_profile?

Open the ***TextEdit*** app. Its like Notepad on Windows.

Navigate to *File → Open...*. In the center drop down, be sure to select *Home*. Or, select the *Home* directory in the left pane. Then, use <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files:

[image]

Select `.bash_profile` and edit away...